# Control other app over gui from my program

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface

I would like to write a simple C++ program for Linux (Ubuntu) to control other GUI programs. For example, to be able to read text labels and put text into entry boxes of other programs written using gtkmm. I have looked at X11 but I don't seem to find any relevant information or examples.

Thank you very much for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is via the [`XTEST`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xtestlib.pdf) (pdf) extension.

An example usage for key events is here: [X11 Fake Key Event Generation using XTest Extension](http://bharathi.posterous.com/x11-fake-key-event-generation-using-xtest-ext).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Java Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class that was designed for this purpose. It can generate mouse & keyboard events etcetera. There is a good documentation and a lot of examples. For example - [Introduction to the Java Robot class in Java](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2212401/Introduction-to-the-Java-Robot-Class-in-Java.htm). Unfortunately, it is Java. You can use X11 API directly, but that is usually too hard.